# Ray Tune | ValueError: Trial returned a result which did not include the specified metric(s) `mse` that `tune.TuneConfig()` expects

Tags: keras, optimization, hyperparameters, ray

I am trying to optimize the keras model (selecting the best hidden size for the first layer) but I got this error

> ValueError: Trial returned a result which did not include the
> specified metric(s) `mse` that `tune.TuneConfig()` expects. Make sure
> your calls to `tune.report()` include the metric, or set the
> TUNE_DISABLE_STRICT_METRIC_CHECKING environment variable to 1. Result:
> {'trial_id': '830fd_00000', 'experiment_id':
> '3d78cf7f46b94e5390f528e95e97aff3', 'date': '2022-08-27_11-11-28',
> 'timestamp': 1661613088, 'pid': 1381126, 'hostname':
> 'arman-GT73EVR-7RE', 'node_ip': '172.30.50.84', 'done': True,
> 'config/threads': 8, 'config/lr': 0.055332536888805156,
> 'config/hidden': 65}

My code is :

```
def train_Broad(config):
    import tensorflow as tf
    batch_size = 128
    epochs = 3
    np.random.seed(0)
    window_size = 200
    x_gyro, x_acc, x_mag, x_mag, q = load_data()

    x_gyro, x_acc, x_mag, q = shuffle(x_gyro, x_acc, x_mag, q)
    Att_quat = Att_q(q)
    x1 = Input((window_size, 3), name='x1')
    x2 = Input((window_size, 3), name='x2')
    convA1 = Conv1D(config["hidden"],11,padding='same',activation='relu')(x1)
    convA2 = Conv1D(10,11,padding='same',activation='relu')(convA1)
    poolA = MaxPooling1D(3)(convA2)
    convB1 = Conv1D(config["hidden"],11,padding='same',activation='relu')(x2)
    convB2 = Conv1D(10,11,padding='same',activation='relu')(convB1)
    poolB = MaxPooling1D(3)(convB2)
    AB = concatenate([poolA, poolB])
    lstm1 = Bidirectional(CuDNNGRU(10, return_sequences=True))(AB)
    drop1 = Dropout(0.25)(lstm1)
    lstm2 = Bidirectional(CuDNNGRU(10))(drop1)
    drop2 = Dropout(0.25)(lstm2)    
    y1_pred = Dense(4,kernel_regularizer='l2')(drop2)
    model = Model(inputs =[x1, x2], outputs = [y1_pred])
model.compile(
        loss="mse",
        optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=config["lr"]), 
        metrics=["mse"])

    model.fit(
        [x_gyro, x_acc], 
        Att_quat,
        batch_size=batch_size,
        epochs=epochs,
        verbose=1,
        validation_split=0.1,
        callbacks=[keras.callbacks.EarlyStopping(monitor="mse", patience=1)])

def tune_Broad(num_training_iterations):
    tune.report(mean_loss="mse")
    sched = AsyncHyperBandScheduler(
        time_attr="training_iteration", max_t=400, grace_period=20
    )

    tuner = tune.Tuner(
        tune.with_resources(train_Broad, resources={"cpu": 4, "gpu": 1}),
        run_config=air.RunConfig(
            name="exp",
            stop={"mse": 0.0001, "training_iteration": num_training_iterations},
        ),
        tune_config=tune.TuneConfig(
            scheduler=sched,
            metric="mse",
            mode="min",
        ),
        
        param_space={
            "threads": 8,
            "lr": tune.uniform(0.001, 0.1),
            "hidden": tune.randint(1, 100),
        },
    )

    results = tuner.fit()
    print("Best hyperparameters found were: ", results.get_best_result().config)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument(
        "--smoke-test", action="store_true", help="Finish quickly for testing"
    )
    parser.add_argument(
        "--server-address",
        type=str,
        default=None,
        required=False,
        help="The address of server to connect to if using Ray Client.",
    )
    args, _ = parser.parse_known_args()
    if args.smoke_test:
        ray.init(num_cpus=4)
    elif args.server_address:
        ray.init(f"ray://{args.server_address}")

    tune_Broad(num_training_iterations=5 if args.smoke_test else 300)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for Tune to access the `mse` metric, you will need to report it from your training function. With Keras, this can be done with the `TuneReportCallback`.

[Here](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/tune/examples/tune_mnist_keras.html) is an example which does this to report the model's `accuracy` metric back to Tune as `mean_accuracy`.